# How display h4 next to icon

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, icons, font-awesome

I use font awesome and when I try to display an icon followed by an h4 the h4 go on the next line and won't stay at the right of the icon.

Here it's my code : `<div><i class="fa fa-mobile fa-3x"></i><h4>Telephone</h4></div>`

[image: Icon with h4 on the next line]

how to make so that the h4 does not appear on the line below ?

Comment: in addition to the below answers you should know that `h4` as all the other headings have a default display as `block` which means they occupy 100% of available width so going on a new line. There are multiple ways to do what you want, you just need a bit of research.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add `display:inline;` with `h4` like given below

**display: block** means that the element is displayed as a block, as paragraphs and headers have always been. A block has some whitespace above and below it and tolerates no HTML elements next to it, except when ordered otherwise (by adding a float declaration to another element, for instance).

**display: inline** means that the element is displayed inline, inside the current block on the same line. Only when it's between two blocks does the element form an 'anonymous block', that however has the smallest possible width.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-AYmEC3Yw5cVb3ZcuHtOA93w35dYTsvhLPVnYs9eStHfGJvOvKxVfELGroGkvsg+p" crossorigin="anonymous"/>



<div><i class="fa fa-mobile fa-3x"></i><h4 style="display:inline;">Telephone</h4></div>
```

Comment: A little explanation why this works would help the user as it looks like he is a beginner in css/html

Comment: Its works because I make it `display:inline;` basically `h4` default `display:block;` that contain full width...

Comment: i meant an explanation inside your answer. With a difference/definition between inline and block elements.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `display : flex;` for this.

I highly encourage you to learn `flex` or `css-grid` for moving elements around on the page with `CSS`.

Flex has many properties, but again, you should really look into it !

Here is your solution :

```
div {

    display : flex;
    align-items : center;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just add a float like this:

```
<style>
  .title-icon{
        float: left
   }
</style> 

<div>
    <i class="fa fa-mobile fa-3x title-icon"></i>
    <h4>Telephone</h4>
</div>
```

Comment: please do NOT recommend using `float` for this kind of scenario. Float is not for layout purposes. You can end up with unwanted results. Float is mostly used for scenarios where you have and image and you want text to wrap around it. There are much better options out there such as flexbox or css grid